# How to avoid duplicate while reloading the scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm creating a 2D Unity game with multiple scenes. Now, I'm trying to add a restart button.

I'm using the code below to move the player from one scene to another without destroying the player:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

And the following code to reload every scene:

```
int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

// Reload all scenes
for (int i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings; i++)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(i, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}

// Load the scene that was active before restart
SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex);
SceneManager.LoadScene("floor1", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
SceneManager.LoadScene("starter scene", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

If I deactivate the script component which contains the DontDestroyOnLoad function, it works well for one scene.

Just a image of script with deactive for better understanding:

[image]

Question:
How can I keep that script inactive while loading scenes and active while playing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `.enabled` see [unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html).
if you have access to your player object you can deactivate `DontDestroy` component with something like this:

```cs
var dontDestroyComponent = playerObject.GetComponent<DontDestroy>();
dontDestroyComponent.enabled = false;
```

and activating it with setting it `true`

---

or you can use singleton design pattern for your player. something like this:

```cs
private static Player _instance;
private virtual void Awake()
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else if (!Equals(this, _instance))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
private virtual void OnDestroy()
{
    if (Equals(this, _instance))
    {
        _instance = null;
    }
}
```

this will destroy every duplicated Player object
you can use these [simple scripts](https://github.com/noobogami/unity-singleton) too.

Comment: 1st provided code perfectly do its job . But if the dontdestroy activates in game  whenever I reload the every scene game makes unidentified problem .